# Modify an array of strings from a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I usually deal with array of strings this way, because it allow me to not specify a character limit :

```
char *names[2] = {"John","Doe"};
printf("%s\n",*((names)));
printf("%s\n",*((names)+1));
```

I am unable to reproduce this while using a struct.

I tried with both `john.names = {"John","Doe"};` and `john.*names = {"John","Doe"}`. But I am getting an expected expression error.

However, I am able to do so during the initialization with `Person john = {{"John","Doe"}};`. So I'm not sure if it's allowed to proceed like this only during initialization.

#### main.h

```
typedef struct Person Person;

struct Person
{
    char *names[2];
};
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "main.h"
int main()
{
    Person john = {{"John","Doe"}};
    john.names = {"John","Doe"}; // Expected expression error
    printf("%s\n",john.names[0]);
    printf("%s\n",john.names[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the "expected expression", am I allowed to do this ?

Comment: @xing yes of course, I am using this to `printf` just before my `return 0`. But what I would like is being able to use brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For initialization of a specific field/attribute, you can do something like the following during declaration:

`Person john = {.names = {"John","Doe"}};`

To initialize additional fields, let's say `address` and `names`, this can be done like the following:

`Person john = {.names = {"John","Doe"}, .address="foo"};`

After declaration, you will have to specify the array index.

`john.names[0] = "John"`

Comment: "After declaration, you will have to specify the array index." So from what I understand, there is no way to use brackets after initialization ?

Comment: To populate multiple indices? i.e. 0,1 at the same time? No.

Comment: @shellwhale: C does not support array assignment — and `john.names = …` is attempting to assign to an array.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are not first class elements in C. You can *initialize* a full array, but you can only *assign* to non array elements, meaning scalars, pointers or structs.

When you write

```
char *names[2] = {"John","Doe"};
```

, it is an initialization, not an assignment. And the following assignment would also choke with a syntax error:

```
char *names[2];
names = {"John","Doe"};    // syntax error here
```

Answer (score 2):

Well , i guess that there are may ways to access the content of a struct ,
the way i learned it on my side is for a structure looking like that
//

`typedef struct struc_person
{
char *name[2];
}    type_person;`

```
type_person->name[0] = value_of_the_first_name;

type_person->name[1] = value_of_the_surname;
```

Comment: That depends what `type_person` represents in your assignment example: if it's a pointer to the `type_person` that you've typedeffed then yes you would use `->` but if it's an instance of the structure then it's `.`. As written this wouldn't compile, but if you meant `type_person` to be an instance of `type_person` then you need to use `.` not `->` here.